# React Native (Expo) iCloud no sync

Tags: react-native, expo, icloud

So I have 2 mac machines and I am a developer. I loved the idea of iCloud Drive because I would be able to share everything on my desktop and documents.

Until I started with vue, react native, ... => projects with node modules.

It's a fact that the node modules folder can get large very quickly. Which causes iCloud Drive to sync for days. It just doesn't work.

There is a solution, if you put .nosync after a file/folder , iCloud won't sync this. So renaming node_modules to node_modules.nosync and creating a link folder node_modules that links to node_modules.nosync works perfectly... for my Vue projects.

But on React Native (I'm using Expo), I can't run my app anymore.

I think it's because I now have 2 node_modules folders. But Vue can handle this and React Native doesn't...

So my question is, has anyone found a solution to do this? Thanks in advance!

Here are some snippets of my error:

(node:65003) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: jest-haste-map: Haste module naming collision:
  Duplicate module name: merge
  Paths: /Users/.../node_modules.nosync/merge/package.json collides with /Users/.../node_modules.nosync/react-native/Libraries/vendor/core/merge.js

This error is caused by `hasteImpl` returning the same name for different files.
    at setModule (/Users/.../node_modules.nosync/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:569:17)
    at workerReply (/Users/.../node_modules.nosync/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:641:9)
    at runMicrotasks ()
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 17636)